# How to remove redirect to www in Wordpress and DirectAdmin

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want remove redirect of my WordPress site from "example.com" to "www.example.com" .
It is my ".htaccess" file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I already know removing redirect to "www" can cause duplicate content. But it is not important for me.I want my domain shown with and without "www" without any redirect.

Comment: Well, this snippet does not cause the redirect from non-www to www. Are you sure there isn't something else in your .htaccess? Or in another apache configuration file? Also check your ISP's settings, sometimes they have a setting in an admin panel of some sort.

Comment: @giorgio : That is exactly my .htaacess content and there is not any redirect in my Redirect segment is DirectAdmin panel.No! ISP setting is OK. But i must check Apache setting of my hosting service.I will check and return.

Comment: FYI: the only thing this snippet does is rewrite everything that is not a file or a directory to index.php. Nothing more, nothing less. But why exactly do you want to get rid of the redirect? Maybe there is another (better) solution to your problem.

Comment: because i redirect pages with plugin from old domain to new domain.And my new domain has different url structure.So i redirect pages manually.Now when i want to submit change of address in Google search console, Google says my old domain (without www) not redirect and redirects to (with www) of my old domain.